# Define several json formats for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app i defined a specific JSON-Format in my model:

```
def as_json(options={})
     { 
         :id => self.id,
         :name => self.name + ", " + self.forname
     } 
end
```

And in the controller i simply call:

```
 format.json { render json: @patients}
```

**So now im trying to define another JSON-Format for a different action but i dont know how?**
How do i have to define another as_json or how can i pass variables to `as_json`? Thanks

Comment: You can pass variables to as_json: `{ render json: @patients.as_json(include_relation: true) }` and define your own conditions following the options

Comment: Ok but i think here i need something else?

Comment: I posted an answer, it's kind of messy but you get the point, dont hesitate to ask anything about it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining hash structure by 'as_json' method, in respective model class i.e User model in (Example 1), it becomes the default hash stucture for active record(i.e., user) in json format. It cannot be overridden by any inline definitions as defined in Example: 2

Example 1:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 .....
  def as_json(options={})
    super(only: [:id, :name, :email])
  end
end
```

Example: 2

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
 ....
  def create 
    user = User.new(params[:user])
    user.save
    render json: user.as_json( only: [:id, :name] )
  end
end
```

Therefore, in this example when create action is executed 'user' is returned in ("only: [:id, :name, :email]") format not as ("only: [:id, :name]")

So, options = {} are passed to as_json method to specifiy different format for different methods.

Best Practice, is to define hash structure as constant and call it everwhere it is needed

For Example
Ex: models/user.rb
Here, constant is defined in model class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
...
 DEFAULT_USER_FORMAT  = { only: [:id, :name, :email] }
 CUSTOM_USER_FORMAT = { only: [:id, :name] }
end
```

Ex: controllers/user.rb

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
 ...
  def create
  ...
  render json: user.as_json(User::DEFAULT_USER_FORMAT)
  end

  def edit
  ...
  render json: user.as_json(User::CUSTOM_USER_FORMAT)
  end
end
```

Cool!

Answer (score 2):

A very ugly method but you can refactor it for better readability:

```
def as_json(options={})
  if options.empty?
    { :id => self.id, :name => self.name + ", " + self.forname }
  else
    if options[:include_contact_name].present?
      return { id: self.id, contact_name: self.contact.name }
    end
  end
end
```

---

Okay, I should give you a better piece of code, here it is:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  if options.empty?
    self.default_json
  else
    json = self.default_json
    json.merge!({ contact: { name: contact.name } }) if options[:include_contact].present?
    json.merge!({ admin: self.is_admin? }) if options[:display_if_admin].present?
    json.merge!({ name: self.name, forname: self.forname }) if options[:split_name].present?
    # etc etc etc.

    return json
  end
end

def default_json
  { :id => self.id, :name => "#{self.name}, #{self.forname}" }
end
```

Usage:

```
format.json { render json: @patients.as_json(include_contact: true) }
```

Comment: In 1 minute i will break your 12k!